# Confusion with the formula for harmonic conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

According to [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicConjugateFunction.html), the harmonic conjugate of a harmonic function $u$ is given by

$$v(z)=\int_{z_0}^z u_xdy-u_ydx+C$$
where $C$ is a constant, while in [here](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/harmonicfunctionmod.html), the harmonic conjugate is given by

$$v(z)=\int u_xdy-\int u_ydx-\iint u_{xx}dxdy$$
where the integral is an indefinite integral. The last term above is no way a constant (since it is an indefinite integral). I am wondering whether there is any relation between the line integral and the indefinite integral.

In conclusion, my question is: why are the above two formulas equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what is actually meant by the second formula. More precisely, what is $$\phi(x,y) =\int \int f(x,y) d\,x d\,y $$ supposed to mean? Note that on both sides $x$ and $y$ are used for the variables, but in a totally different context. Once you fix the domain on the rhs, it does not even depend on $x$ or $y$.

The author of the text your second link is pointing to is rather sloppy with regard to dependend and independent variables.

I'm also under the impression that there is a mistake in his reaoning. In equation 3-27 he claims that
$$v(x,y) = \int v_x(x,y) d\, x + C(x)= \int v_y(x,y) d\, y + C(x) $$
with a function $C$ (a single function!) depending on $x$ alone.

Ignoring for a moment what these integrals might mean let's look a bit closer at what is actually true. Note that
$$v(s,t) =\int_{s_0}^s v_y(x,t) d\, y + v(s_0,t) = \int_{t_0}^t v_x(s,y) d\, x + v(s,t_0)$$

(assuming the domain on whic $v$ is defined allows to write down these integrals).

This shows that, when you integrate wrt $x$ the assumed function $C$ depends on the second free variable while, when you integrate wrt $y$, that function will depend on the first variable, and the two functions will by no means be equal to each other.

The claim in 3-27, therefore, is not correct in the way it is stated.

I won't answer the question about the formula you are after, but I would not know what the second formula actually means and there is at least one error in the attempt to derive it, so I would not trust it.

Rather, I suggeest to try to figure the formula out yourself, with some more care paid to the difference between dependent and independet variable.

Comment: The function $u_{xx}$ is just some function of two variables, so I can integrate with respect to $x$ and then with respect to $y$, right? So $u_{xx}=2$ would give $2xy

Comment: @TomGrubb but how do you determine the domain of integration?

Comment: @TomGrubb you see, I'm not saying that integrating a function wrt. two variables does not make sense. I'm critizising the equation at the top of my answer, which I have taken from the link the OP is pointing to (I did remain the functions, but kept the overall structure). The problem I'm having here is that, on the lhs you have a function of $x$ and $y$, while the function on the rhs depends on the domain of integration, and it is by no means clear what this has to do with the $x$ and $y$ from the lhs. Also, the main point of my answer is to point out an error in the calculations on that site.